# Check condition field datetime is greater than or equal to currentdatetime in mongo db using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to mongodb. I have a Date field named `conEnd` whose value is "2020-01-18T16:26:00.000+00:00".
I need to check a condition , where the current date time is greater than or equal to the `conEnd` datetime, unsubscribe socket.

Here is my code.

```
    const today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate());
    const date = (today.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + today.getDate() : today.getDate();
    const month = (today.getMonth() < 10) ? '0' + (today.getMonth() + 1) : today.getMonth() + 1;
    const currentDate = today.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + date;
    const hours = today.getHours();
    const minutes = today.getMinutes();
    const currentdatetime:any= '2021-01-18T16:26:00.000+00:00'//for testing I hard code the time. Otherwise I used currentDate+'T'+hours+':'+minutes+':00.000+00:00';
```

I have one field in mongodb that matches the current time. But whenever I use the below code I get empty array [].

```
    this.stockcontests.find({conEnd:currentdatetime},{conEnd:1}, function (err, result) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log(result)
        }
    });
```

Without condition `{conEnd : currentdatetime}` the above query gives me `conEnd` in this format :

```
 conEnd: 2020-01-18T16:26:00.000Z
```

I also tried checking this condition but failed `{conEnd : {$gte : currentdatetime} }`
How can I properly execute the condition, where `conEnd >= currentdatetime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ISODate to compare dates in MongoDB:

```
"$gte" : new Date("2021-01-10T10:03:46Z")
```

ISODate works because that is the format of your date in DB.

example

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({'sampleField': {$gte: new Date('2021-01-10T10:03:46.000Z')}})
```

You can check more details here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/

Comment: But it says cannot find ISODate.

Comment: ISODate is a part of MongoDB and is not available in your case. Instead you should be using Date object and the MongoDB drivers(e.g. the Mongoose ORM that you are currently using) will take care of the type conversion between Date and ISODate behind the scene. I have updated the code above

Comment: Worked with Date(). Thank you :-) .